# js error handling when finding the name of the current page displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

On load the variable pageName checks the html of the page and stores the value of the current page. I am having an issue with my Index.html page since I am using rails, and my Index is my Root page. So when I am on my Home page, I receive an error when the document.location.href function is ran since there is no name for the root page.

I tried to put in an Error check but am not sure exactly how to set it up. Thank you for your time. If you need more information to help just sent me a message please.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var pageName = document.location.href.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];

if pageName.error() = true {
  $( ".navHome" ).addClass( "selectedPage" );
} else {
  switch (pageName) {
  case 'news':
    $( ".navNews" ).addClass( "selectedPage" );
    console.log("news");
    break;
  case 'media':
    $( ".navMedia" ).addClass( "selectedPage" );
    console.log("media");
    break;
  case 'about':
    $( ".navAbout" ).addClass( "selectedPage" );
    console.log("about");
    break;
  default:
    console.log("none");
   }
 };
});
```

Comment: `if pageName.error() = true {` is not valid JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are mixing up with JavaScript, but your syntax is wrong and you have an issue where there is no error() method for a string and if there is no match, you can not reference the first index since there is no array.

So you need to change how you are referencing the match and your syntax for the if statement which requires the parenthesis around the clause.

```
var pageName = document.location.href.match(/[^\/]+$/);  //Just run the match, no referencing the first index
if (!pageName) { //check if there is not a match with a falsey check (could use (pageName===null)
    $( ".navHome" ).addClass( "selectedPage" );
} else {
    switch (pageName[0]) {  //grab the match here, instead of in the reg exp line
        case 'news':
        break;
        /* rest of cases */
    }
}
```

Comment: @Teemu What are you talking about an array? What does `match()` return if there is no match? It returns `null` which is a false value so the check is 100% correct. Now in the switch I reference the first index which is the match.

Comment: @Teemu, No in the OPs code, they were using [0] which is a string at the point, but when there is no match they are trying to reference an index of null which is the error the OP talks about.

Comment: works perfectly. Thanks for the explanation, I understand what i was doing wrong now.